# How to return result from angular2-modal, or in general from ng2-components

Tags: promise, angular, return-value

I am using the this great [angular2-modal](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal) but can't figure out how to return a result value from my custom modal.

I instantiate it like this:

```
    let dialog: Promise<ModalDialogInstance>;
    let bindings = Injector.resolve([
        provide(ICustomModal, { useValue: this.gewaehltesBild })
    ]);
    var self = this;
    dialog = this.modal.open(
        <any>ImagecropperComponent,
        bindings,
        new ModalConfig("md", true, 27));


    dialog.then((resultPromise) => {
        return resultPromise.result.then((result) => {
            this.lastModalResult = result;
            this.mitarbeiter.avatarImg = this.gewaehltesBild;

            $(self.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#bildSelector').val("");
        }, () => this.lastModalResult = 'Rejected!');
    });
```

I have tried to send my returnvalue with

```
this.dialog.close(this.croppedImage);
```

but result is always null. Is there a convention in angular2 how to return values from components, that is used by angular2-modal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Works fine for me, I too am using custom dialog and here is how i catch the result

```
  var dialog = this._modal.open(VideoPlayerComponent,
      resolvedBindings,
      new ModalConfig('lg', true, 27));
    dialog
      .then((d) => d.result)
      .then((r) => { console.log(r);  }, (error) => { console.log(r); });
```

When i call `close` on the instance

```
this._dialog.close("Hello");
```

It does print `Hello`

Comment: it works, I think I had a typo in the method that generates the return-value inside of the modal... :/ thx